# electronic speed control of 3 post compound DC motor

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

I've got a 12V DC winch motor with two field posts and an armature post (compound motor). Currently direction is controlled by four solenoids.

[image: Solenoid direction control]

Here's a diagram which boils this down two the two modes:
[image: Testing Diagram]

I think speed can be controlled via PWM, but the standard H-Bridge most brushed DC motor controllers come with doesn't seem like it would support this configuration.

Comment: You've asked a shopping question at the end. This is a 'no-no' and will quickly get your question closed. Change it into a design question.

Comment: How do you know  that it is a compound motor? Where is the paralell feild connected?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to keep the solenoids for direction switching, you should be able to use a single very-large MOSFET for speed control.

Although the best place to do the PWM control is in the ground lead of the armature, that node probably isn't available to you.

So: setup a MOSFET and its driver as a floating switch and place it in series with the hot end of the armature.

Alternatively, place it in series with the battery (+) lead that feeds the solenoid contacts.

Doing a floating MOSFET power stage isn't difficult and your PWM frequency can be fairly low - low hundreds of Hertz.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a H-bridge for this application. You just need a heavy duty 12 V motor speed controller or PWM switch in the +12 V line.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhnvAu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>